# I want to know how to use these pronouns (die, man and es) for they

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to know how to use these pronouns (die, man and es) for they.
For example: Das Team hat gut gespielt und die haben gewonnen.

Comment: Please avoid greetings and thanks, especially in the title. Instead, proofread  your question before sending.

Comment: **Es** is worth several articles. You have to be more specific about what you don't understand about how to use es.

Comment: Actually, in your example one would rather say "... und _sie_ haben gewonnen.", so I am having difficulties to understand, what exactly you want to know. could you specify?

Answer (score 2):

```
Das Team hat gut gespielt und die haben gewonnen.
```

**Das** Team ist sächlich und daher hat **es** gewonnen.

> Das Team hat gut gespielt und es hat gewonnen.

Da das Team bekanntermaßen eine Gruppe von Spielern ist kann man, sprachlich etwas unsauber, auch sagen:

> Das Team hat gut gespielt und sie haben gewonnen.

Aber nur, wenn die Sätze zuvor keinen anderen Kandidaten für das *sie* aufdrängen:

Der Trainer spricht: 
Das Glück ist nicht immer bei den Tüchtigen. Die Gegner waren lauffaul und technisch limitiert, während wir eine gute Kondition gezeigt haben. Das Team hat gut gespielt und sie haben gewonnen.

Hier liegt mit *Gegner* eine 3. Person Plural vor, auf die das *sie* bruchlos passt. Ein klassischer Gegensatz von *wir* und *sie*, der auch mit die noch funktioniert:

> Die Gegner waren lauffaul und technisch limitiert, während wir eine gute Kondition gezeigt haben. Das Team hat gut gespielt und die haben gewonnen.

Das zweite Beispiel eignet sich aber noch weniger für den schriftlichen Ausdruck als das erste. Im mündlichen Ausdrück ist aber die Betonung eine andere, je nach dem ob man mit *sie* die impliziten Spieler des gleichen Teams meint, oder eines anderen Teams.

Answer (score 1):

When used as a pronoun, **die** and *der*, and *das*, too, are *demonstrative*. A pointing finger.

> **Die** hat gewonnen.

**This she** has won.

> **Die** haben gewonnen.

**These** have won.

---

**Man** is the *indefinite* pronoun. It's used whenever no-one in particular should be addressed.

> Das kann **man** so machen. *(also note the demonstrative **das**)*

***One*** can do it this way.

Sometimes it's not *one* but *people*.

> **Man** trank und lachte.

***People*** drank and laughed.

---

**Es** is worth several articles. You have to be more specific about what you don't understand about how to use **es**.